# iOS in-app subscriptions - do not show the iTunes Apple-ID dialog

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

When implementing subscriptions checking (iOS, in-app), each time a subscription is checked by the app in background, this dialog appears to the user:

[image]
It appears at each app start.
How to get rid of it? Is it possible not to show it?
I repeat: this is about subscriptions CHECKING, not actually byuing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this happens when you test in sandbox mode. But in production if user is already logged in , this won't pop up.

Comment: @Yar same thing happened to me for auto-renewable in-app purchases when I tested in sandbox mode. But it didnt happen when I test in production mode, after downloading the app from appstore. I think this happens because sandbox test accounts are not real iTunes accounts so their credentials aren't stored like real ones.